# IE11 failed to send out jquery post request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried the following code:

```
  $.post(sumoUrl, contentUploadLog, function(data) {
    console.log('after logged', data);
  });
```

It works fine in Chrome. But doesn't work in IE11. In IE 11, the console doesn't generate any error message, but the after logged message is not displayed.

I have browsed other questions about this topic and was wondering whether it has anything to do with cross domain, so I have checked the below code as well:

```
      $.ajax({
          url: sumoUrl,
          cache: false,
          data: contentUploadLog,
          type: "POST",
          crossDomain: true,
          success: function() {
              console.log("after logged");
          }
      });
```

However, it is also not working properly.

Any reason why?

Comment: 1) Add a `fail` handler, eg `.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)})`. 2) Do you even know what the `crossDomain` property does? It's probably not what you think 3) Even IE has a *Network* console where you can see requests and most importantly, responses from AJAX calls

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the response, I have checked the Network console and there is no post event there.

Comment: In chrome and IE there is nothing show on the console, Use `network` tab to see the response.

Comment: In that case, whatever is meant to trigger this code is not working and the code in your question is insufficient for an answer to be provided

Comment: @Phil I am pretty sure it is working. First, it is document.ready(). Second,it is working in chrome. Third, I have added a console.log just in front of this piece of code and that is displaying well in IE.

Comment: and there are no other errors or messages in your console at all? How are you opening the HTML page in your browser? Via the `http://` scheme or is it `file:///`?

Comment: @Phil I don't see any other errors. And the page is functioning well. Just not posting the logs well. It is via http://

Comment: How is `contentUploadLog` defined? One thing that IE was very picky about was trailing commas in object literals, eg `{ this: 'is', not: 'valid', in: 'IE', }`. Check for any such instances in your code

Comment: @Phil It is very general string. Something like "Hello world". Not a json one. Will that cause any issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

You tried adding `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >` to the page header?

Add `cache: false` in your ajax call like this :

```
$.ajax({
          url: sumoUrl,
          cache: false,
          data: contentUploadLog,
          type: "POST",
          success: function() {
              console.log("after logged");
          }
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I am still not seeing any post request in the network panel.